# My SIM card was stolen. What info besides contacts does it store?

Tags: simcard

And can they break the PIN number easily?

Comment: Are you using a phone from 2007? Modern phones don't store your contacts on the SIM anymore.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Some apps/phones still synchronize contacts there, although it is becoming more and more rare.

Comment: In order to steal the sim card, did the thief have physical access to your actual phone and/or other devices?

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, it stores (or more correctly *embodies*) your **Identity** (it's in the name) as far as your service provider is concerned. Anyone who has your not-yet-deactivated SIM *is you*, for the purpose of receiving calls or texts (and associated 2FA), incurring charges, etc.

Call your service provider *Yesterday* to have them kill the SIM.

As for breaking the PIN, does [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/58758/is-it-possible-to-crack-a-pin-puk-code-on-a-phone-sim-card) enlighten? It's the top hit I got from [my first Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=phone%20SIM%20PIN%20cracking).

Answer (score 1):

## Carrier Identity

As @mlp already pointed out, this is your identity on the carriers network. From Wikipedia:

> A subscriber identity module or subscriber identification module
> (SIM), [...] is intended to securely store the international mobile
> subscriber identity (IMSI) number and its related key, which are used
> to identify and authenticate subscribers [...]. It is also possible to
> store contact information on many SIM cards.

## Online Authentication

Additionally newer SIM cards also can hold and run programs, used for enhanced identification. They claim it's even legally binding. See the [Mobile identity management Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_identity_management) for more information.

An application is the ["Mobile ID" identification service](http://www.mobileid.ch). This is for example used by the [Mobile ID login by the Swiss PostFinance Bank](https://www.postfinance.ch/en/private/products/digital-banking/mobile-id.html) and others.

Comment: Thanks! Does SIM contain call logs?

Comment: Minor nit: my username here is all-lowercase - my middle initial is ELL not EYE.

Answer (score 1):

SIM cards do not generally store call logs. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIM_card#Data) for a list of data that is stored on a SIM. Note however that having your SIM might allow someone to access your account with your mobile provider and get call logs from them.